# WFE Load Balancer Issue SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Occasionally I get sorry something went wrong when navigating around the site, if I refresh 1-3 times, then the page loads. If I had 3 WFEs (assuming the issue) what are some specific things I can do to fix or redirect away from a wfe?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to get which WFE is bad.To identify the bad server you can try following things.

1. Hit directly the Server( by passing the Load balancer) use the host file entry. in host file enter the ip of 1st wfe and url of the web app. repeat this for all 3 servers.
2. You can take the server out of load balancer. Take 2 server out of load balancer then test the renaming server, do the same for all server and catch the bad server.
3. lastly, if you get the correlation id then run the [merge-splogfile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and collect the logs from server then you will know which server is bad and what is the reason.